# How to define regex "password":"[123456]" for masking

Tags: regex, logging, logback, spring-logback

I use logback (logback-gelf vs.1.1.0) to log in my spring boot application. It has configuration xml file and I try to write regular expression to mask passwords in this configuration file. I write this:

```
%replace(%msg){'(password...)(\d{6})(.)', '$1****$3'}
```

It works with `{"password":"123456"}` and give an output `{"password":"****"}`.
However, it cannot work with:

`{"client_id":["account"],"password":["111111"],"grant_type":["password"]}`

I want to make it `{"client_id":["account","password":["****"],"grant_type":["password"]}`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that it always considers 3 characters in between the string "password" and the actual password.

Do this instead:

`%replace(%msg){'(password"\S+?")(\S+?)(".+)', '$1****$3'}`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1RiXZW/3)